# Convert non-ascii punctuation to ascii

Tags: ruby, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have the following string:

> Your résumé’s a non–encyclopædia

Note the **’**, **é** and **æ** are non-ascii. I want to leave **é** and **æ** intact, but replace the ’ with ascii quote: **'**.

How can I make such conversion in Ruby (not Rails)? My database is UTF8 and I still wanna store the accented characters, including kanjis, Chinese, etc., but just wanna replace the punctuation.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what’s wrong with `s.gsub /[‘“”’]/, {'“' => '"', '‘' => '\'', '’' => '\'', '”' => '"'}`?

Comment: Because the punctuation could be more than just a quote, it could be something more which I wouldn't know.

Comment: And “smth you wouldn’t know” is supposed to be changed to _what_? BTW, `/\p{Punct}/` will catch all punctuation.

Comment: Perhaps this would help: http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/current/docs/designDoc/UDF/unicode/NormOperations/mapSymbolToAscii.html

Comment: Yes, that article does look like a good starting point, and @mudasobwa has also given you a good hint. The next step is for you to attempt to write your own code. Once you've written some code, if you're still stuck feel free to come back and edit your question to include the code you've written. This article will be helpful for getting a good response: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this gem that works exactly what I wanted - https://github.com/qwuen/punctuate

Just do `.punctuate!`:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'punctuate'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> "Your résumé’s a non–encyclopædia".punctuate!
=> "Your résumé's a non-encyclopædia"
```

Answer (score 1):

`"’".bytes` returns the bytes of character which is `[226, 128, 153]`
loop through every character via `each_char` and compare each character's bytes with `[226, 128, 153]` then replace that character with the normal ' byte which is [39] `[39].pack("c*")`